# Error in in installing an old version of a R package

Tags: r, package

I tryed to install from file an old version of RgoogleMaps package with this command

```
install.packages("F://RgoogleMaps_1.1.9.15.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type="source")
```

but i found this error message:

```
* installing *source* package 'RgoogleMaps' ...
** package 'RgoogleMaps' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
ERROR: a 'NAMESPACE' file is required
* removing 'C:/Users/Famiglia Mazza/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RgoogleMaps'
* restoring previous 'C:/Users/Famiglia Mazza/Documents/R/win-library/3.1/RgoogleMaps'
Warning in install.packages :
  running command '"C:/PROGRA~1/R/R-31~1.2/bin/x64/R" CMD INSTALL -l "C:\Users\Famiglia Mazza\Documents\R\win-library\3.1" "F://RgoogleMaps_1.1.9.15.tar.gz"' had status 1
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘F://RgoogleMaps_1.1.9.15.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status
```

what can I do? I'm using R on Windows

Comment: Use an older version of R?

Comment: I'm using version 3.1.2. Why is not correct?

Comment: At some point R demanded all packages have namespaces. It looks like this package was developed before then, so you will need to use a version of R that doesn't have that requirement. I think it was first introduced in R 2.14.0 with transitional support until R 3.0.0.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I will change version. If you post this like answer, i will choose as the best

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In [R 2.14.0](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.14.0/NEWS.R-2.14.0.html) a requirement was made that all packages had namespaces, but as a transitional arrangement those that didn't would have one automatically generated at install time.

> A package R code but without a ‘NAMESPACE’ file will have a default
>   one created at R CMD build or R CMD INSTALL time, so all packages will
>   be installed with namespaces. A consequence of this is that
>   .First.lib() functions need to be copied to .onLoad() (usually) or
>   .onAttach(). For the time being, if there is an auto-generated
>   ‘NAMESPACE’ file and no .onLoad() nor .onAttach() function is found
>   but .First.lib() is, it will be run as the attach hook (unless the
>   package is one of a list of known exceptions, when it will be run as
>   the load hook).

However, by [R 3.0.0](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/3.0.0/NEWS.R-3.0.0.html) this transitional arrangement was ended:

> The transitional support for installing packages without namespaces
>   (required since R 2.14.0) has been removed. R CMD build will still add
>   a namespace, but a .First.lib() function will need to be converted.
>
> R CMD INSTALL no longer adds a namespace (so installation will fail),
>   and a .First.lib() function in a package will be ignored (with an
>   installation warning for now).
>
> As an exception, packages without a ‘R’ directory and no ‘NAMESPACE’
>   file can still be installed.

Therefore, I suggest you use an older version of R to run this package. One prior to R 3.0.0 should suffice, and the latest one prior to that is [R 2.15.3](http://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/old/2.15.3/).